# FormRequest no retorna JSON cuando las validaciones fallan (LARAVEL 8, REACT, AXIOS)

Tags: laravel, reactjs, axios

Estoy usando React para una SPA, Laravel 8 para el backend y los FormRequest para validar el request.

Resulta que al fallar la validación, laravel me redirecciona a la pagina anterior en vez de devolverme un JSON con los errores, hay he intentado usar aplication y content type application/json desde axios, tambien [intente con esta repuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54504816/laravel-api-not-showing-message-from-request-validation) y no funciono ya que laravel retorna un error 500, con ningún método he podido obtener los errores de validación en JSON.

Axios:

```
const submitData = async () => {
    console.log("asdasd");
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:80/";
    try {
      await axios.get("sanctum/csrf-cookie");
      const response = await axios.post("api/products", null, {
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json",
          "Accept": "application/json",
        },
      });

      console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
      setSuccess(false);
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

FormRequest:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreProductRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'nombre' => 'required|string',
            'precio' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
            'cantidad' => 'required|numeric',
        ];
    }
}
```

El error que obtengo:
[image: El error que obtengo:]
El error que espero obtener
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Logre acceder con esta linea error.response.data.errors sin embargo sigo sin saber porque al hacer un console.log(error) no obtengo los errores

Comment: Claramente estás obteniendo un error de validación 422, pero no podrás ver el objeto que retorna si haces un console.error(), usa un console.log, simplemente.

Comment: @JonatanLavado obtengo casi el mismo resultado, cuando voy a network y veo la peticion que fallo y luego a la pestaña de response, si veo los errores de laravel, pero hace algunos años yo podia acceder a esos errores simplemente haciendo un console log, ahora no se porque el procedimiento es más largo.

Comment: SI mal no recuerdo creo que antes podia hacer eso porque estaba usando fetch, y axios funciona diferente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para acceder a los errores que mencionas, es necesario **entender** lo que es retornado por `axios` cuando hay un error. En su [documentación](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors) puedes verlo con un claro ejemplo:

```
axios.get('/users')
  .catch(function (error) {

      if (error.response) {
          console.log(error.response.data);
          console.log(error.response.status);
          console.log(error.response.headers);
          console.log(error.toJSON());
      }

  });
```

Comment: Gracias, no sabia que axios tiene esa pagina de documentación.